# Dos Batch to compare if two text files are the same by line by line operation

Tags: batch-file, text

text1.txt

```
aaa aaa aa1
bbb bbb bb2
ccc ccc cc3
ddd ddd dd4
```

text2.txt

```
000004
aaa aaa aa1
bbb bbb bb2
ccc ccc cc3
ddd ddd dd4
END
```

I got two files. Let focus on text2.txt first. 000004 means there are 4 effective lines.

And what i want to do is to use batch to skip first line untill END and compare the middle four lines with text1.txt contents.

It may involve loops or nested loop to compare each line line by line. And if the middle 4 lines match the text1.txt exactly,

```
      echo valid file
else (echo invalid file)
```

Any ideas?
Really Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `fc.exe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see, now I know the use of 000004. Make sure the "4" is indicating lines available, if 5th row from text2.txt and text1.txt is matched but the first line is 000004, it may returns Invalid file.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set bool=1
set /a count=0
set /a count_true=0
set /a skip_count=0
set access_bool=0

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (text2.txt) do (
    if !bool! == 0 (
        call :Next_loop Next_content !skip_count! !access_bool! blank_param
        set /a skip_count+=1
        if %%a == !Next_content! (
            set /a count_true+=1
        )
    )
    if !bool! == 1 (
        set first_line=%%a
        set lines_to_skip=!first_line:~-1,1!
        call :Next_loop Next_content !skip_count! !access_bool! check_lines_in_loop

        if !check_lines_in_loop! gtr !lines_to_skip! goto result
        if !check_lines_in_loop! lss !lines_to_skip! goto result

        set bool=0
    )
)


:result
if !count_true! == !lines_to_skip! (
    echo Valid file!
) else (echo Invalid file!)
pause >nul


:Next_loop
set /a check_lines
set /a Next_count=0

for /f "tokens=*" %%b in (text1.txt) do (
    if %3 == 0 (
        set /a check_lines+=1
    )

    if !Next_count! == %2 (
        set %1=%%b
    )
    set /a Next_count+=1
)
if %3 == 0 (
    set %4=!check_lines!
    set %3=1
)
```

Comment: Dear dark fang,
Thanks for your work, but in `text1.txt`
If i type in one extra line at the bottom like`12dsf3585 dsf` ,the program seems still claim this is valid, can you have a look on it, cause i am still rookie in batch.

Comment: I know the meanings in `%%a` and `%%b` in the for loop but 
what does %1 %2 %3 %4 means?Do they store value at the initialization because i don't see initialization of %2? Brief guideline is good enough.Thanks.

Comment: @KenyKeny If you want to pass a variable through a `call` command like `call :Next_loop Next_content !skip_count!`. 1) *Next_content* is still an unknown variable yet we can assign it in `:Next_loop` e.g. `set %1=5`, where `%1` represents *Next_content*. 2) *!skip_count!* is an assigned variable, so we can assign a new / use it in `:Next_loop` e.g. `set /a assign_variable=%2`, where `%2` represents *s!kip_count!*

Comment: Dear dark fang,
Your code is useful, but i have to modify some codes for the new request. In text2, the first line becomes 00000420150629, and i tried to make some changes in if !bool! == 1 (),what i put down is

`if !bool! == 1 (
        set first_line=%%a
  set first_line=!first_line:~0,6!
  set /a first_line = 1!first_line!-1000000 
  set lines_to_skip=!first_line!
  echo !lines_to_skip!
  call :Next_loop Next_content !skip_count! !access_bool! 
........................        
set bool=0
    )`
But it doesn't work, and said sth like "system could not locate specified path"

Comment: Any changes and comments, i did try but i just not able to do so, thanks a lot

Comment: Do put text2.txt in other directory?

Comment: Oh,dark fang,the minor request is solved now. Your program is working fine.
The next question is that i don't quite get what is the logic to verify two files. I want to know & learn more. Starting from this ` call :Next_loop Next_content !skip_count! !access_bool! check_lines_in_loop
`, i lost. I know it would jump to the next_loop like a function call, what does `Next_content !skip_count! !access_bool! check_lines_in_loop` means? May be too much question,thanks.

Comment: @KenyKeny I've posted an answer to your question

Comment: Hi Dark Fang,

Your code works fine with my example text files ,but when i use this program check text files with about 15,000 lines, the program takes about 12 hours to complete. And I also found that some parameter like blank_para has been initialized but not used.

So i am thinking if there any ways to simplify your code, any comments?

Comment: Ya, blank_param is indeed a useless argument, you can remove it. Anyway, batch is slow, if I write a code that increment value by 1 in a loop and output in a text file, (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4...), batch only increment and output up to 70. While C++, the fastest programming language (maybe not, but it's still very fast), can increment and output up to 800,000 ~ 1,000,000 !!! By the way, is it really took so long to finish? I think add `echo Finished!!` at the end of the 1st `for /f` loop is a good practice to know when it is finished.

Comment: Yeah, it took quite a while. And how do you find using two arrays to store the line contents, and then using one for-loop to compare each content?

Can an array in batch script handle a large amounts of strings?Say 15,000 lines?

Comment: Array wasn't available in batch... You can manually make an array like this. `@echo off`
`setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`

`set increment=0`

`for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (text2.txt) do (`
 `set array[!increment!]=%%a`
 `set /a increment+=1`
`)`
`echo %array[0]%`
`echo %array[4]%`
`pause >nul`

Comment: `array[0]` is the first element, which is the first line of text2.txt

Answer (score 1):

Answer to KenyKeny question.
`call :Next_loop Next_content !skip_count! !access_bool! check_lines_in_loop`
Basically it's calling `:Next_loop` with 4 arguments: Next_content, !skip_count!, etc...
**Arguments with no "! !" signs**
1. Arguments like this is variable that haven't been assigned yet, like an unknown variable.
2. You can assign a value to it in `:Next_loop` by `set %1=hello` (%1 will be discuss later on)
**Arguments with "! !" signs**
1. Arguments like `!skip_count!` is an assigned variable, which has value in it.
2. You can use this argument in `:Next_loop` like `echo %2` since this argument had been assigned before.
3. You can also assign a new value to it.
**What is %1, %2, %~1, etc.. ?**
1. It represents value passed by arguments. `%1` indicates the first argument(Next_content), where `%2` indicates the second argument(!skip_content!)
2. `%~1` is basically a quotation(" ") mark filter. E.g :

```
@echo off
call :function "hello"

:function
echo %1
echo %~1
```

First line echo out *"hello"* where second line filtered out quotation marks and left only *hello*.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my own coding by referring to google, i used array method. Everyone, let's have a look, i have tried it and it can verify whether two files are the same.I add some **extra echo** to show that some arrays are null.Make sure two text files are in the same directory.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set textfile1=text1.txt
set textfile2=text2.txt

rem Verify textfile1 and textfile2
echo Now check whether text1.txt is the same as the text2.txt.
echo.

echo Read in textfile2 into array2
set arr_counter2=0
for /f "skip=1 delims==" %%a in (%textfile2%) do ( 
  if "%%a" equ "END" ( 
  echo You reach "END"
  goto :break1 
) else (
echo !arr_counter2!
set arr2[!arr_counter2!]=%%a
rem echo %%array2[!index!]%%
set /a arr_counter2+=1
echo !arr_counter2!
pause
)
)
:break1
echo number of elements in array = !arr_counter2!

echo !arr2[0]!
echo !arr2[1]!
echo !arr2[2]!
echo !arr2[3]!

echo !arr2[4]!
echo !arr2[5]!
echo !arr2[6]!
echo !arr2[7]!
echo !arr2[8]!
echo !arr2[9]!
pause 
echo.









echo Read in textfile1 into array1
set arr_counter1=0
for /f "delims==" %%b in (%textfile1%) do ( 
rem if "%%a" equ "END" ( 
rem echo You reach "END"
rem goto :break1 
rem ) else (
echo !arr_counter1!
set arr1[!arr_counter1!]=%%b
rem echo %%array1[!index!]%%
set /a arr_counter1+=1
echo !arr_counter1!
pause
)
)

echo number of elements in array = !arr_counter1!

echo !arr1[0]!
echo !arr1[1]!
echo !arr1[2]!
echo !arr1[3]!

echo !arr1[4]!
echo !arr1[5]!
echo !arr1[6]!
echo !arr1[7]!
echo !arr1[8]!
echo !arr1[9]!
pause 
echo.




set /a final_index=!arr_counter1!-1 
rem compare each element from [0] to [final_index]
for /l %%n in (0,1,!final_index!) do (
rem echo !arrayline[%%n]!
if !arr1[%%n]! equ !arr2[%%n]! (
echo same content.
pause 
) else (
echo wrong!
pause 
goto :eof
)
)
echo all contents are the same

pause
```